# Создание связи таблица+запрос с группировкой

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть таблица `ship_naming_comsostav`. В ней три поля:

- `ship_id` — идентификатор судна,
- `shipnaming_name` — номер названия судна (каждое судно может иметь до 15 названий),
- `shipnaming_number` — номер названия для текущего названия.

Нужно, чтобы запрос возвращал идентификатор судна, его название и количество доступных названий для идентификатора судна. Делаю так:

```
SELECT ship_id,shipnaming_name ,shipnaming_number ,cid 
FROM ship_naming_comsostav t1
inner JOIN (SELECT ship_id AS sid, count(*) AS cid 
FROM ship_naming_comsostav GROUP BY sid HAVING count(*)>1) t2 ON t1.ship_id = t2.cid
```

Виснет сервер. Может быть, нужно составить запрос по-другому?

Comment: Для каждого поля укажите алиас таблицы.

Comment: Поставил
SELECT t1.ship_id,t1.shipnaming_name ,t1.shipnaming_number ,t2.cid 
FROM ship_naming_comsostav t1
inner JOIN (SELECT ship_id AS sid, count(*) AS cid 
FROM ship_naming_comsostav GROUP BY sid HAVING count(*)>1) t2 ON t1.ship_id = t2.sid

не работает

Comment: А (primary key) ключ у вас какой в таблице ship_nameing_comsostav ?  Какое название для судна нужно вернуть если их несколько ?

Comment: Ключ shipnaming_name
мне не нужно возвращать название, оно уже есть, мне нужно вернуть кол-во названий для ship_id
тоесть название не имеет особой нагрузки
надо получить таблицу

идентификатор судна | текущее название | номер текущего названия | кол-во названий

Comment: @SergeyP приведите результат 
show create table ship_naming_comsostav;
а также пример данных с двумя разными ship_id чтобы для каждого ship_id было больше одной записи

Comment: @Alexus
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ship_naming_comsostav` (
  `ship_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipnaming_number` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipnaming_name` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`shipnaming_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Вот часть таблицы:

ship_id | shipnaming_number | shipnaming_name 

147006 | 13 | Huang He 22

147006 | 14 | Chang Bai

147006 |15 | KUNLUN

В принципе мне нужно последнее число 15
то есть я должен получить (по данному примеру такую запись:

147006 |15 

и так далее по всем идентификаторам судна

Comment: @SergeyP  То есть у вас 15 здесь  и количество и номер в базе одновременно ?

Answer (score 0):

Код вашего запроса будет примерно следующим:

```
select a.*
from ship_naming_comsostav a
inner join (
    select ship_id,max(shipnaming_number) as shipnaming_number 
    from ship_naming_comsostav group by ship_id) b
using(ship_id,shipnaming_number)
```

Comment: Та же ситуация - виснет сервер.

Comment: @SergeyP Сколько записей в таблице ?  
select count(*) from ship_naming_comsostav;

Comment: порядка 108000 и будет расти

Comment: @SergeyP Нужны подробности зависания сервера. Ваш сервер? Хостинг ? Может только mysql зависает ? Сколько времени вы ждали выполнения запроса? Простые запросы с таблицей выполняются ? (select * from ship_naming_comsostav where ship_id=147006)

Comment: подробности сказать не могу
доступ к логам у админа, его нет сейчас.
Жду хоть час, хоть два, потом процесс убиваю.
Простые запросы нормально выполняются.

Comment: @SergeyP 108000 записей это немного. Еще было бы неплохо увидеть show processlist в mysql. Возможно что какие то проблемы с самой таблицей. Вариант 1: выполнится ли вот такой запрос (select * from ship_naming_comsostav). Вариант 2,  создайте копию этой таблицы и попробуйте на ней.

Comment: Отображает строки 0 - 29 (107,814 всего, запрос занял 0.0007 сек.)

Comment: Судя по вашему ответу вы выполняли запрос в phpmyadmin (всего 30 записей из 107814.) Попробуйте выполнить этот запрос в оболочке mysql.